# Fetching css in json file

Tags: javascript, css, json

Is there a way to fetch styles that are stored in a json file without using any framework or node npm package?

I've been doing some research and cannot find anything that helps me create a style library for a very limited in resources HMI using pure vanilla JS.

Comment: "Vanilla JS" usually means "JS in a web browser without third-party APIs" but you've mentioned Node.js so it isn't clear if you are talking about Node.js or a browser.

Comment: Where is this JSON file? How you fetch data from a file at an HTTP URL and how you do so from a local file system are completely different problems.

Comment: That said, fetching data from URLs or files and extracting data from JSON are three very common problems that have many, many resources here and elsewhere on the WWW, so this feels [exceptionally under-researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068).

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you've selected. [tag:fetch] tells you not to use it.

Comment: Re: _"Is there a way to fetch [...] a json file [...] ?"_ Yes. The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).